# What can be unlocked in San Francisco Rush 2049 in multiplayer?

Tags: san-francisco-rush-2049

I play [San Francisco Rush 2049](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_Rush_2049) (on Dreamcast, if it matters) with a friend, and we want to unlock features together in 2-player mode.

Is this even possible or do you have to play in single-player mode?

I read that you can unlock a new single-player mode, when you get 1000000 points in stunt mode. I assume that you don't have to get these points in *one* session, as it seems impossible. The points seem to get saved in the player's score table, so you'll have to collect these, I guess.

How do you get new stunt levels? Do you have to collect all gold and silver coins? Would only one of us need all coins, or do we both need to get all coins? If only one of us has all coins, can we nevertheless play the new level together?

How do we get new cars? Only in race mode? Again, is it possible to unlock them in 2-player mode?

Are there new battle maps or even weapons to unlock?

Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out:

- You *can* unlock levels in multiplayer mode.
- Each player has his own score board, so each player can unlock levels himself.
- You don't need to collect the points in *one* round, your points are saved.
- If only *one* player has unlocked a level, you can still play this new level together in multiplayer.

According to [this page (German)](http://www.spieletipps.de/n64/san-francisco-rush-2049/tipps/3199/1/), you need the following points to unlock features in Stunt and Battle mode. Note, the page is about the N64 version, so I'm not 100% sure if this applies to the Dreamcast version, too (but I'd think so; I heard that only the soundtrack and the graphics are different).

### Stunt mode

- 100000 points: stunt level "Disco"
- 250000 points: stunt level "Oasis"
- 500000 points: stunt level "Warehouse"
- 1000000 points: new single-player mode "Obstacle"

### Battle mode

- 100 kills: battle level "Downtown"
- 250 kills: battle level "Plaza"
- 500 kills: battle level "Roadkill"
- 1000 kills: battle level "Arena 8"